# Is it possible to control another character besides Shepard?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Throughout the course of the single-player game, do you ever take the reins of any other character besides Shepard? I'm aware that you have up to two squad mates to boss around. I'm also aware that during multiplayer play you control other characters.

**What I'm looking for is whether or not you ever directly control any other character in the game at any point. If so, how can you do it, and when does it occur?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope... the only time you control another is in ME2, when you have to control Joker. It's like the opening for Dead Space 2.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. You're always with the Shep.